# Android Instant Apps podem controlar deep links?

Tags: android

Preciso desenvolver um protótipo de app muito simples.

O app precisa ser compatível com Android Instant Apps.
O usuário irá abrir o app sem instalá-lo (Instant Apps).
O usuário irá usar o Chrome para navegar para https://example.com/path (deep link).
O app mostrará uma dialog com "Hello World", automaticamente, pois o usuário navegou para https://example.com/path (deep link no AndroidManifest).

Isso é possível com Instant Apps ou apenas com apps instaláveis?

Obrigado.

Comment: Este é o stack em português. Traduza sua pergunta ai.

Comment: @Articuno, nossa que gafe minha, nem percebi.

Comment: @Articuno, tem como mover para o StackOverflow em inglês?

Comment: Basta você remover a pergunta e refazer la :) Ou simplesmente traduzir e manter aqui,

Comment: @Articuno, traduzido, vlw pelo toque.

Answer (score 2):

> **Resumindo**: Sim é possível.

### **Explicação adicional**

Para as Android Instant Apps recomenda-se o uso dos Android App Links (que equivale ao IOS Universal Links) ao invés dos Deep Links.

### **Deep Links**

Requisitos:

- Android 4.2

Permite-nos associar a nossa app á uma URI. Quando o utilizador dá um click no link e se tiver a app instalada no celular, a app será aberta. Caso não tiver a app instalada, irá ocorrer um erro **“Page Not Found”.**
Tu podes associar o link à tua app no Intent-filter da seguinte forma:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Aceita URI  "http://example.com/path" -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="exemple.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/path" />
    </intent-filter>
```

E depois na tua activity:

```
Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
    String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();
    Log.i("MyApp", "Deep link clicked " + uri);
}
```

### Android App Links

Requisitos

- Android 6.0
- Deves ter um website a funcionar.

Permite associar o teu website com o a tua app. 
O utilizador faz um click no link e vai para uma activity específica da tua app. Caso ocorra uma falha com o link, ao invés de dar o erro **“Page Not Found”**, o link irá direcionar o utilizador á tua pagina web.
**Tanto a versão instantânea como a versão instalável da tua app devem implementar o Android App Links.**

O Android studio (versões mais recentes) permite-nos associar a nossa app com o nosso website de uma forma muito simples, basta utilizar o App Links Assitant e seguir os passos.
Com o App Links Assistant, tu irás definir o host e o path. Em seguida, ele irá gerar um ficheiro assetlinks.json. Tu deves anexar esse ficheiro ao teu website sobre a pasta `/.well-known`. O App Links Assistant irá definir o teu Intent-filter e fazer o resto do trabalho. :)

**assetlinks.json**

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.helloworld",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["49:9C:ED: . . .  "]
  }
}]
```